# Accessing current window when disposing of subscription

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following code:

```
var observable = ... subscribe to event here ...

var windows = observable.Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(240));

aggregatedWindows = windows.SelectMany(
    window => window.Aggregate(new Context(), AggregateContext));

subscription = aggregatedWindows.Subscribe(OnWindow);

... later

subscription.Dispose();
```

Imagine a scenario when I am in the middle of processing a window and someone has requested that my app should close. I'm going to dispose of this subscription, which will stop the events being processed, however I'm also going to lose the last window of information.

I'm not sure what the best way to deal with this is...

I could store local state with the last seen window as it is passed through the aggregation function (but this seems wrong)...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the subscription of the aggregation, you could operate on the windowing - which is what you primarily want to keep connected to for the last window to arrive, and use a timeout to disconnect in case it takes too long to partition.

A separate class is used here because using `Create` makes it Auto Detach - which immediately disconnects the observer after the dispose call has been made. So fundamentally, the meaning of Dispose is what's been changed here.

```
    public static IObservable<T> DeferDisconnection<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return new ClosingObservable<T>(observable, timeout);
    }


    public class ClosingObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
    {

        private readonly IConnectableObservable<T> Source;
        private readonly IDisposable Subscription;
        private readonly TimeSpan Timeout;

        public ClosingObservable(IObservable<T> observable, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            Timeout = timeout;
            Source = observable.Publish();
            Subscription = Source.Connect();
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            Source.Subscribe(observer);

            return Disposable.Create(() => Source.Select(_ => new Unit())
                                                 .Amb(Observable.Timer(Timeout).Select(_ => new Unit()))
                                                 .Subscribe(_ => Subscription.Dispose())
                                                 );
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
            var disposable =
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                      .Do(Console.WriteLine)
                      .DeferDisconnection(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                      .Subscribe();

            Console.ReadLine();

            disposable.Dispose();

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how this solves the problem. It looks like the DeferDisconnection will wait a little before disposing, but if the window is large then this will cause the app to wait a long time to close. Is that correct?

Comment: @jonnii That's why there's a timeout argument - it disconnects when the next value arrives or if it takes too long which is the timeout parameter.

Answer (score -1):

This works, as confirmed by a partial window being displayed at the end.

```
class Program
{
    public class Context
    {
        public int count;
    }

    static Context AggregateContext(Context c, long i)
    {
        c.count++;
        return c;
    }

    static void OnWindow(Context c) { Console.WriteLine(c.count); }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var canceled = new Subject<bool>();

        var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1)).TakeUntil(canceled);

        var windows = observable.Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        var aggregatedWindows = windows.SelectMany(
            window => window.Aggregate(new Context(), AggregateContext));

        var subscription = aggregatedWindows.Subscribe(OnWindow);

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        canceled.OnNext(true);
        subscription.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine( @"Output should have been something like 30,30,30,30,10" );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```